# HERE map isn't displayed well on mobile

Tags: here-api

i have issue when using mobile to view app, when i go to map section it's not displayed well.

[image: this is how it looks]

this is how it looks, and it's not the same on all devices (this is SS taken from ZTE Blade A6 lite which has version 7.1.1), on some newer androids it's fine.

I was wondering are there some limitations to implementation or it's known issue?

Answer (score 0):

If the map is rendering fine on other android devices, then problem could be with device and not how the sdk works. you can refer to github for efficient map rendering practices followed in our sample code implementation(https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-sdk/4.2.0.0/dev_guide/content/topics/examples.html). Is there any specific error which is logging at the application level while map rendering. Do you mind sharing to know the issue better.